# Align div from bottom to top

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Here is a html bar chart.How to make the vertical bars in chart appear from bottom to top instead of the way its appearing now.

Here is the html

```
<div class="chart">
    <div style="height: 40px; width: 5px; float: left; padding-bottom: 0px">
        4</div>
    <div style="height: 80px; width: 5px; float: left;">
        8</div>
    <div style="height: 150px; float: left;">
        15</div>
    <div style="height: 160px; float: left;">
        16</div>
    <div style="height: 230px; width: 13px; float: left;">
        23</div>
    <div style="height: 420px; float: left;">
        42</div>
</div>
```

Here is the csss

```
 .chart div
    {
        font: 10px sans-serif;
        background-color: steelblue;
        text-align: right;
        padding: 3px;
        margin: 1px;
        color: white;
    }
```

Here is a link to [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/va8tJ/)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could use `display: inline-block` instead of float which will allow you to use `vertical-align: bottom`.

Like this:

```
.chart div {
  font: 10px sans-serif;
  background-color: steelblue;
  text-align: right;
  padding: 3px;
  margin: 1px;
  color: white;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: bottom;
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/davidpauljunior/va8tJ/5/)

Comment: +1. You should use [`inline-block` instead of `float`](http://www.sitepoint.com/give-floats-the-flick-in-css-layouts/)  whenever you can.

Comment: +1: Short and sweet. Agree with above comment. Also, personally, I'd override the `width` as well, because he's using varying widths which is kind of... pesky. :D